# Why no corresponding subroutine call in machine code dump when calling strcpy()?

Tags: c, macos, assembly, gdb

I am working through the book 'Hacking: The Art of Exploitation' by Jon Erickson.

In one part of the book he gives C code and then walks through the corresponding assembly using gdb, explaining the instructions and memory activity.

I am working along in Mac OS X, so things are a bit different than he presents in the book (he is using Linux).

Anyway, I have this C program:

```
1 #include <stdio.h>
2 #include <string.h>
3 
4 int main()
5 {
6         char str_a[20];
7 
8         strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
9         printf(str_a);
10 }
```

Here is the corresponding otool object dump (I have just included main):

```
_main:
0000000100000ea0    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000ea1    movq    %rsp,%rbp
0000000100000ea4    subq    $0x30,%rsp
0000000100000ea8    movq    0x00000189(%rip),%rax
0000000100000eaf    movq    (%rax),%rax
0000000100000eb2    movq    %rax,0xf8(%rbp)
0000000100000eb6    leaq    0xd4(%rbp),%rax
0000000100000eba    movq    %rax,%rcx
0000000100000ebd    movq    $0x77202c6f6c6c6548,%rdx
0000000100000ec7    movq    %rdx,(%rcx)
0000000100000eca    movb    $0x00,0x0e(%rcx)
0000000100000ece    movw    $0x0a21,0x0c(%rcx)
0000000100000ed4    movl    $0x646c726f,0x08(%rcx)
0000000100000edb    movq    %rcx,0xe8(%rbp)
0000000100000edf    xorb    %cl,%cl
0000000100000ee1    movq    %rax,%rdi
0000000100000ee4    movb    %cl,%al
0000000100000ee6    callq   0x100000f1e ; symbol stub for: _printf
0000000100000eeb    movl    0xf4(%rbp),%eax
0000000100000eee    movq    0x00000143(%rip),%rcx
0000000100000ef5    movq    (%rcx),%rcx
0000000100000ef8    movq    0xf8(%rbp),%rdx
0000000100000efc    cmpq    %rdx,%rcx
0000000100000eff    movl    %eax,0xd0(%rbp)
0000000100000f02    jne 0x100000f0d
0000000100000f04    movl    0xd0(%rbp),%eax
0000000100000f07    addq    $0x30,%rsp
0000000100000f0b    popq    %rbp
0000000100000f0c    ret
0000000100000f0d    callq   0x100000f12 ; symbol stub for: ___stack_chk_fail
```

OK. You will notice the subroutine call to printf():

```
0000000100000ee6    callq   0x100000f1e ; symbol stub for: _printf
```

But where is the call to strcpy()?

There are two further anomalies. First of all, if I set a breakpoint in gdp for strcpy():

```
break strcpy
```

The program zips through its execution without stopping. It seems as if strcpy() isn't actually getting called.

Second, when I compiled the code:

```
gcc -g -o char_array2 char_array2.c
```

I got a warning:

```
char_array2.c: In function ‘main’:
char_array2.c:9: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
char_array2.c:9: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
```

I'm not sure if that is related to the missing subroutine call, but I thought I would include it as a data point anyway.

It almost seems to me as if the compiler has decided strcpy() is not necessary and has optimised the code to work without it. The program does work as expected, printing 'Hello, world!' to the standard output, but this missing call to strcpy() has me wondering exactly what is happening.

In Erickson's example in the book there *is* a call to strcpy() so perhaps there is a difference in how his compiler and my compiler are working. I am on LLVM:

i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2

Any ideas would be gratefully received!

Thanks in advance, and I hope you find this one interesting.

Tom

Comment: Your explanation sounds entirely plausible; what compiler flags are you using?

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

Comment: @mu Thank you. So, instead of actually making a call to strcpy() GCC replicated the functionality by itself? Do I have that right? Very interesting. I wonder why Erickson had an actual call instruction in his machine code, even through he was using GCC. I guess maybe he had different preferences set up.

Comment: Pretty much. Add `-fno-builtin` or `-fno-builtin-strcpy` to your compiler flags you should see a call to libc's `strcpy`.

Comment: @mu Hmm. Actually the -fno-builtin flag does not seem to have had the expected effect. Possible bug?

Comment: Perhaps try `-ffreestanding`?

Comment: Thanks @R but I already tried that one as well. No dice! I also tried -O0 (not that it should have had any effect, but I thought I'd give it a go). Weird.

Comment: I'm getting in over my head so I'll stop here. For what's it's worth, I'm seeing less disassembled output and a `memcpy` call that could be replacing `strcpy` (the string's size is known at compile time after all).

Comment: Can anybody else with OSX (and llvm) reproduce this behaviour? My exact source code is above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's right here:

```
0000000100000ebd    movq    $0x77202c6f6c6c6548,%rdx
0000000100000ec7    movq    %rdx,(%rcx)
0000000100000eca    movb    $0x00,0x0e(%rcx)
0000000100000ece    movw    $0x0a21,0x0c(%rcx)
0000000100000ed4    movl    $0x646c726f,0x08(%rcx)
```

Comment: Thanks. Should there not be a 'call' or 'callq' instruction in there? Apologies; I am new to assembly, and the syntax used in the book (linux based) is quite different to what I am seeing under OS X.

Comment: There's no reason a `call` or `callq` (or any transfer of execution) is needed to perform `strcpy`, especially when one of the arguments is a string literal.

Comment: Perhaps to better elaborate, **C is not high-level assembler**. A C compiler's job is to ensure that the observable behavior of the compiled program match what's specified by the language standard. There are plenty of places no `call` instruction will take place when you call a function, for example: (1) it's defined in the same translation unit and can be inlined, (2) its behavior is specified by the standard and the compiler can achieve the behavior directly inline by itself.

Comment: Yes, from @mu's link above I now understand that strcpy() is a built in function, so no need to transfer to a subroutine. The strcpy() functionality is replicated in the instructions you copied. Cool stuff! Thanks.

Comment: BTW, a better compiler would just store the string literal in the read-only data segment with the `\n` removed, and call `puts`...

Comment: @R..: calling `puts` instead of `printf("...\n")` is not necessarily an optimization; that's because `puts()` still needs to perform console output, determine the string length, and _append_ `\n` again. If the compiler is really good, it might choose to `write(0, "...\n", ...)` for you, or at least `fwrite("...\n", 1, ..., stdout)`. Curious to see if any does ;-)

Comment: Changing it to `write` is definitely not conformant. The interaction with any other code using stdio (buffering issues) will be different. `fwrite` could be used, but it's going to result in slightly larger code. Calling `puts` (which gcc does in certain cases) is mainly an optimization for size.